# Is it craft an item "on the forge" or "in the forge"?

Tags: grammar

Or is it something else?

Here's some additional context.

> In Skyrim, we can craft items **on the forge** if we have the requisite
>   material. My level 12 Nord already crafted 10 pieces of iron armor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Forge" as a noun can mean either a furnace for softening metal or the building that houses such a furnace.

In the meaning of "furnace," few people are comfortable enough inside one to do much of anything when it is hot enough to make metal malleable. It is likely fairly uncomfortable to work on top of the furnance as well.

In the meaning of "building" it is certainly possible to work metal **in** a building and is far more comfortable when it is raining and snowing. It may be possible to work the metal **on** the roof of the building that houses a furnace, but I doubt that doing so is at all common.

In short, "on a forge" is grammatical, but makes no sense.

I suspect that what is meant is "anvil" rather than "forge." Metal is indeed worked **on** an anvil.

Video games like Skyrim are not noted for their deep knowledge of anything except possibly quaternions, which are a hot topic in computer graphics. It is possible that the developers know the difference between a hammer and a bloom or between scarfing a slab and tempering it, but I would not count on it. Working metal has its own vocabulary. Those who have been involved in such work know the vocabulary. Those who have not been involved are likely to misuse that vocabulary.

EDIT: I grew up within hearing distance of Pittsburgh Hammer and Forge and my first job was in a steel works so I actually have clue about what working with malleable metal involves.

Comment: Comfort isn't the only concern when making something "on a forge".  Generally speaking, forges are made of materials chosen for their structural stability at high temperatures, *not* their impact resistance while at high temperature.  They have that too, but over time, you will damage your forge if you do that.  And yet, I've heard 'on the forge' all over the place.  I may have even heard it on the Saugus Iron Works tour once, though at least there there was a correction made shortly thereafter... that time.

Comment: @EdGrimm I admit that when I worked at the rolling mill, my co-workers were not necessarily careful in their prose. (They were very careful with hot metal though, and I had to agree with their priorities).

Comment: I absolutely agree with those priorities. When I was in metal shop, I *never* corrected one of my classmates when they used this term to describe what they were actively doing, even though I was just as autistic then, and didn't have nearly the degree of sophistication in managing it as I do now. Our instructor, however, was not so lenient. (I was in that class because the semester before, that teacher had given me the best computer class I'd had up to that point. A great teacher in a subject I had no interest seemed like a better plan than a unknown teacher in a subject I had little interest)

Comment: So "in a forge" is correct?

Comment: You can craft metal objects **in** a forge, where "forge" is used in the sense of a building or an open space that contains a furnace, tools, anvils, molds, fuel, etc. You can craft metal objects **on** an anvil or **in** a mold. But it makes no sense to say **on** a forge, whether you are using "forge" to mean a furnace or to mean a workspace dependent on a furnace.

Comment: You can also craft items **at** a forge or **with** a forge.

Comment: @JasonBassford I agree, but that was not the question.

Comment: The question asked about the use of prepositions. You don't *have* to mention others, but it helps your answer if you do.

Comment: @JasonBassford You are right. But you covered it. I was too focused on the on/in distinction.

Comment: Ok so in, at or with a forge, although with a forge sounds weird.

Comment: "With a forge" meaning "with a furnace for making metal malleable" may make perfect sense in the right context. The problem here is that the question was dual. It asked about "on" or "in" a forge. It also asked about other prepositions. The answer to the more general question is going to depend on context, which you did not give. In the normal case, "in" or "at" is likely to be the relevant preposition, but circumstances alter cases.